# Application of Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, inverse

This is a seemingly easy exercise. Yet I am not sure if I am missing any finer details here as this is listed as one of the challenging problems on Dr. Epstein's (Upenn) course site for real analysis. http://www.math.upenn.edu/~cle/amcs608/ps0.pdf

I am doing Problem 7 on this webpage as I am learning the material on my own.

Define a map from $\Bbb R^{2}$ to itself by setting
$$F(x, y) = (\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x, \cos x \cos y − \sin x \sin y).$$ Does there exist a point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ such that $F$ is locally invertible in a neighborhood of $F(x_{0}, y_{0})$. You must prove your answer.

What I did:

$$DF(x,y)= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos x \cos y-\sin x \sin y & -\sin x \sin y+\cos x \cos y \\
-\sin x \cos y-\cos x \sin y & -\sin y\cos x-\sin x\cos y \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$\det {DF(x,y)}= \cos (x+y) \sin (x+y)- \sin (x+y) \cos (x+y)=0. $$

It seems $F$ is not invertible anywhere, is it correct or have I missed some finer details?

Comment: If $DF$ is invertible, then $F$ is locally invertible. However, it's not an "only if" condition, so you can't conclude from $DF$ non-invertible that $F$ is not locally invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another point of view:

Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$, then after flipping coordinates
$$
F(x,y) = \exp(i(x+y))=\exp(ix)\exp(iy)=(\cos x + i \sin x)(\cos y + i \sin y)
$$
so it cannot be locally invertible because for all $x,y$ and all $h$
$$
F(x+h,y-h)=F(x,y)
$$

Comment: Ok, but is my approach not formal enough? Please suggest

Comment: No, it is ok - formal enough and correct. I just wanted to show you another point of view.